# Conditionally restart activity from notification in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I have two Activities, MainActivityCaller and MainActivity, with activity MainActivityCaller starting activity MainActivity via the startActivity() method.

From a notification, I would like to launch activity MainActivity if it has been paused but exists in a task back stack (done with code below), but to launch MainActivityCaller if it does not (ie. if the MainActivity instance has been destroyed either by the user or the system).

MainActivity broadcasts the following when the user's location changes

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    final Location finalLocation = location;

    final Intent restartMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    sendOrderedBroadcast(
            new Intent(LOCATION_CHANGED_ACTION),
            null,
            new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @TargetApi(16)
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    if (getResultCode() != RESULT_OK) {

                        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, restartMainActivity, 0);

                        Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(context)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentText("Lat = " + Double.toString(finalLocation.getLatitude()) + "\nLong = " + Double.toString(finalLocation.getLongitude()))
                        .setContentIntent(pi)
                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning));

                        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        nm.notify(0, nb.build());
                    }
                }
            },
            null,
            0,
            null,
            null);
}
```

MainActivity also has a broadcast receiver instantiated in its onCreate method (abbreviated version below)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (isOrderedBroadcast())
                setResultCode(RESULT_OK);
        }
    };
}
```

With the receiver being registered in the onResume method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(LOCATION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

And unregistered in the onPause method

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

In the Manifest file, MainActivity is declared to only be launchable in one task

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

Right now this either creates or restarts MainActivity (depending on if MainActivity was destroyed or stopped).  How can this be modified to launch MainActivityCaller when no instance of MainActivity exists in any task back stack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to register your broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml, make the receiver be a public Java class, and have the receiver (re)start the activity.

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".RestarteActivityBR"
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.intent.restart" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in RestartActivityBR.java:

```
public class RestartActivityBR extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {
        Intent main = new Intent(context, AppMain.class);
        main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this before but I would try to keep the pointer to my `Notification` object as a class variable, and later changing the `contentIntent` property to a different PendingIntent. Make a simple hard coded test to see if this works.

If the above method works then... `MainActivity` needs to notify the service that it is there or not (the service can't guess), so you could use onPause() and onResume() to notify the service that the Activity is present.